# I'm trying to restrict a cell to specific characters using excel

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

i'm trying to force the date format of mm/dd/yyyy in a cell in excel using excel for mac v 16.60.  the column format *must* be text.

i'm not great with visual basic, so i'm hoping this is accomplishable via formula or data validation.

i've tried the following:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/forcing-a-particular-format-for-date-data-entry-in/fe2d68c5-12e2-45c5-afb7-a5d1be732bfe

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3653-excel-only-allow-date-in-cell.html
(#2 under allow only date format in specific cells with data validation function)

is there a way to require 2 digits, a slash, 2 more digits, a slash, then 4 digits in a text-formatted cell?

Comment: Why do you need it to be text?  Why not us Data Validation to ensure the content of the cells is a date?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - the cell format has to be text because of the usage of the document.  it's populated by one team and used by another for a different function.  the secondary team's import sheet has the date in text format and that's controlled by the ui that team 2 is importing the doc to.

i need to ensure that the content of the cell is in mm/dd/yyyy format. if there's a way to do that using data validation, please share? i haven't been able to figure it out nor find it out via google search.

admittedly, it's the end of a very long monday and my brain is zapped.

Comment: mm/dd/yyyy is a date format available in Data Validation, if missing in your list of choices then add with custom.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Excel formula for text. Place a regular date in cell A2 then in another cell type `=TEXT(A2,"mm/dd/yyyy")`.

If the answer works for you, the expectation is that you checkmark it and upvote it. If the answer does not work for you you add a comment at the bottom and the problem you experience.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! that will make another column on the worksheets, which i'm trying to avoid.  the workbooks and usage are super nuanced with multiple teams working in them.  ultimately, i'm trying to 'bulletproof' the workbook to prevent user error further down the workflow, while keeping the sheet as simple as possible for population.

Comment: sometimes the answer you think you want is not the answer. I recommend you use@cybernetic.nomad recommendation.

Comment: Your trying to control data types in excel which is rather difficult because excel has put so much effort to control all data types. Another option is to not use excel and use something that gives you complete control.